# In Debian CMake cant find 'libmosquitto'

Tags: c, cmake, mosquitto

Im trying of compile a cmake project of C code in a Raspberry Pi with Debian 10, the CMakeList.txt search for package first, when ask for 'libmosquitto' show the error:

```
 Checking for module 'libmosquitto'
  No package 'libmosquitto' found.
```

Already have installed this package with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmosquitto-dev
```

Before this, the CMake show another error for the package json-c, but after install it with apt-get install, the problem gone, but now for this library the CMake not recognize mosquitto.

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of your CMakeLists.txt (or all of it) by editing it into your question.

Comment: No package 'libmosquitto' : `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libmosquitto.pc` ...... If it's say an old project, the package file `libmosquitto.pc` may not be searched for in this special Debian location ?

Answer (score 0):

locate libmosquitto.pc
and then add this path to **PKG_CONFIG_PATH**
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="Actual_Path to libmosquitto.pc"
This worked for me.